# How to compute the Feynman propagator for the Proca field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator, second-quantization

I was repeating each step of the exercise 6.4 of the Greiner's book "Field quantization"  when I discovered that there is a passage which I can't reproduce, the calculations are lengthy and I'm sorry if the question will be too long.

We are treating the Proca field (massive spin-1 neutral particle), so we decompose the associated quantum field as
$$A^{\mu}(x)=∫ d^{3}kN_{k}\sum_{\lambda=1}^{3}(\hat{a}_{k\lambda}\epsilon^{\mu}(k,\lambda)e^{-ik\cdot x}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k\lambda}\epsilon^{\mu}(k,\lambda)e^{ik\cdot x})\hspace{1cm}N_{k}:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2ω_{k}}(2\pi)^{3}}$$
To compute the Feynman propagator we have
$$\Delta_{F}^{\mu\nu}(x-y)=<0|T(A^{\mu}(x)A^{\nu}(y))|0>=∫ d^{3}kd^{3}k'N_{k}N_{k'}\sum_{\lambda\lambda'}\epsilon^{\mu}(k',\lambda')\epsilon^{\nu}(k,\lambda)\cdot$$
$$\cdot\biggl(θ(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-i(k'x-ky)}<0|\hat{a}_{k'\lambda'}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k\lambda}|0>+θ(y_{0}-x_{0})e^{i(k'x-ky)}<0|\hat{a}_{k\lambda}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k'\lambda'}|0>\biggr)=$$
$$=∫ d^{3}kN_{k}^{2}\sum_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\mu}(k,\lambda)\epsilon^{\nu}(k,\lambda)\biggl(θ(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)}<0|\hat{a}_{k'\lambda'}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k\lambda}|0>+θ(y_{0}-x_{0})e^{ik(x-y)}<0|\hat{a}_{k\lambda}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k'\lambda'}|0>\biggr)$$
$$=-∫ d^{3}kN_{k}^{2}(g^{\mu\nu}-\frac{k^{\mu}k^{\nu}}{m^{2}})\cdot\biggl( θ(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)}<0|\hat{a}_{k'\lambda'}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k\lambda}|0>+θ(y_{0}-x_{0})e^{ik(x-y)}<0|\hat{a}_{k\lambda}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k'\lambda'}|0>\biggr)$$
where we used the completeness relation for the polarization vectors and the commutation relations of the ladder operators. At this point we should convert the $k^{\mu}$ into gradients operators, keeping in mind that the derivative acts also over the step function
$$∂_{x}^{\mu}(θ(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)})=g^{\mu0}∂_{x_{0}}\theta(x_{0}-y_{0})-iθ(x_{0}-y_{0})k^{\mu}e^{-ik(x-y)}$$
$$\Rightarrow∂_{x}^{\mu}∂_{x}^{\nu}\biggl(\theta(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)}+θ(y_{0}-x_{0})e^{ik(x-y)}\biggr)=$$
$$=∂_{x}^{\mu}\biggl(g^{\nu0}δ(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)}-iθ(x_{0}-y_{0})k^{\nu}e^{-ik(x-y)}$$
$$-g^{\nu0}δ(y_{0}-x_{0})e^{ik(x-y)}+iθ(y_{0}-x_{0})k^{\nu}e^{ik(x-y)}\biggr)=$$
$$=g^{\mu0}g^{\nu0}δ'(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)}-ig^{\nu0}δ(x_{0}-y_{0})k^{\mu}e^{-ik(x-y)}-$$
$$-ig^{\mu0}δ(x_{0}-y_{0})k^{\nu}e^{-ik(x-y)}-iθ(x_{0}-y_{0})k^{\mu}(-ik^{\nu})e^{-ik(x-y)}-$$
$$-g^{\mu0}g^{\nu0}(-δ'(y_{0}-x_{0}))e^{ik(x-y)}-ig^{\nu0}δ(x_{0}-y_{0})ik^{\mu}e^{ik(x-y)}+$$
$$+ig^{\mu0}(-δ(y_{0}-x_{0}))k^{\nu}e^{ik(x-y)}+iθ(y_{0}-x_{0})ik^{\mu}k^{\nu}e^{ik(x-y)}$$
$$=-k^{\mu}k^{\nu}\biggl(\theta(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)}+θ(y_{0}-x_{0})e^{ik(x-y)} \biggr)-i(g^{\mu0}k^{\nu}+g^{\mu0}k^{\nu})\cdotδ(x_{0}-y_{0})\biggl(e^{-ik(x-y)}+e^{ik(x-y)}\biggr)+$$
$$+g^{\mu0}g^{\nu0}δ'(x_{0}-y_{0})\biggl(e^{-ik(x-y)}\color{red}{+}e^{ik(x-y)}\biggr)$$
The Greiner instead of the plus that I emphasized with the red color reports a minus sign, and I can't see why is there.

EDIT:As Dennis showed, the problem was the sign of $δ'(x_{0}-y_{0})$. However the exercise then proceed as follow: recall that the scalar Feynman propagator is
$$iΔ_{F}(x-y)=∫ d^{3}kN_{k}^{2}\biggl(θ(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)}+θ(y_{0}-x_{0})e^{ik(x-y)} \biggr)$$
so from the previous relations
$$iΔ_{F}(x-y)=-i∫ d^{3}kN_{k}^{2}(g^{\mu\nu}-\frac{k^{\mu}k^{\nu}}{m^{2}})\biggl(θ(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)}+θ(y_{0}-x_{0})e^{ik(x-y)} \biggr)=$$
$$=(-i)∫ d^{3}kN_{k}^{2}(g^{\mu\nu}+\frac{∂_{x}^{\mu}∂_{x}^{\nu}}{m^{2}})\biggl(θ(x_{0}-y_{0})e^{-ik(x-y)}+θ(y_{0}-x_{0})e^{ik(x-y)} \biggr)+$$
$$+\frac{(-i)}{m^{2}}∫ d^{3}kN_{k}^{2}(ig^{\mu0}k^{\nu}+ig^{\nu0}k^{\nu})δ(x_{0}-y_{0})\biggl(e^{-ik(x-y)}+e^{ik(x-y)}\biggr)-$$
$$-\frac{(-i)}{m^{2}}∫ d^{3}kN_{k}^{2}g^{\mu0}g^{\nu0}δ'(x_{0}-y_{0})\biggl(e^{-ik(x-y)}-e^{ik(x-y)}\biggr)$$
$$=-(g^{\mu\nu}+\frac{∂_{x}^{\mu}∂_{x}^{\nu}}{m^{2}})iΔ_{F}(x-y)+\frac{1}{m^{2}}∫ d^{3}kN_{k}^{2}(g^{\mu0}k^{\nu}+g^{\nu0}k^{\mu}) \biggl(e^{-ik(x-y)}+e^{ik(x-y)}\biggr)+$$
$$+\frac{(-i)^{2}}{m^{2}}∫ \frac{d^{3}k}{2(2\pi)^{3}}g^{\mu0}g^{\nu0}δ(x_{0}-y_{0})\biggl(e^{-ik(x-y)}+e^{ik(x-y)}\biggr)=$$
$$=-(g^{\mu\nu}+\frac{∂_{x}^{\mu}∂_{x}^{\nu}}{m^{2}})iΔ_{F}(x-y)\color{red}{-}\frac{g^{\mu0}g^{\nu0}}{m^{2}}δ^{4}(x-y)$$
I don't understand why we dropped the second term (it's written that is unphysical, why?), also the book write a factor $i$ with the minus one in red.

Comment: Consider writing a more descriptive title. "Exercise X of Book-Y" is (barely) meaningful to those who possess the book and contains no information about what the question actually is (which appears to be about signs in a result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error seems to be that you assume $\delta'(y_0-x_0)=\delta'(x_0-y_0)$, which, however, is not true. Since $\delta(x_0-y_0)$ is an even "function", its derivative must be odd, so
$$
\delta'(y_0-x_0)=-\delta'(x_0-y_0) \ ,
$$
which takes care of your sign problem.

(See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097610/trying-to-prove-that-the-first-derivative-of-diracs-delta-function-is-odd) for a less handwavy explanation.)

**Update**

About the second problematic phase factor: I think it is just an error in substitution, but let us do the derivation. To keep things simple, let $x-y \rightarrow x$ (in the end, it can be restored).

We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
i\Delta_{\mu\nu}(x)
=&
-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
\left(g_{\mu\nu}-\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{m^2}\right)\left[\Theta(x_0)\exp(-ikx)+\Theta(-x_0)\exp(+ikx)\right] \\
=&
-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
\left(g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{m^2}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu\right)\left[\Theta(x_0)\exp(-ikx)+\Theta(-x_0)\exp(+ikx)\right] \\
&-\frac{i}{m^2}\delta(x_0)
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
(g_{\mu 0}k_\nu+g_{\nu 0}k_\mu)\left[\exp(+i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})+\exp(-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})\right] \\
&+\frac{1}{m^2}g_{\mu 0}g_{\nu 0}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
\delta'(x_0)\left[\exp(-ikx)-\exp(+ikx)\right] \\
=&
-\left(g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{m^2}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu\right)i\Delta(x) \\
&-\frac{4i}{m^2}g_{\mu 0}g_{\nu 0}\delta(x_0)
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
k_0\exp(+i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}) \\
&+\frac{1}{m^2}g_{\mu 0}g_{\nu 0}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
\delta'(x_0)\left[\exp(-ikx)-\exp(+ikx)\right] \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In the last equality, we used that the second term is nonzero only for $\mu=\nu=0$ (so $g_{\mu 0}k_\nu+g_{\nu 0}k_\mu \rightarrow 2g_{\mu 0}g_{\nu 0}k_0$), and the two terms are equivalent in the integrand (c.f. the substitution $\vec{k}\rightarrow-\vec{k}$). Since $k_0=\omega_k$, we find
$$
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
k_0\exp(+i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})
=\frac{1}{2}\delta(\vec{x}) \ .
$$
As for the third term, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_3&=
+\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
\delta'(x_0)\left[\exp(-ikx)-\exp(+ikx)\right] \\
&=
-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
\delta(x_0)
\left[(-ik_0)\exp(-ikx)-(ik_0)\exp(+ikx)\right] \\
&=
+i\delta(x_0)\delta(\vec{x})
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting everything together:
$$
i\Delta_{\mu\nu}(x)=
-\left(g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{m^2}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu\right)i\Delta(x)
-\frac{i}{m^2}g_{\mu 0}g_{\nu 0}\delta(x) \ .
$$

The second term seemingly breaks Lorentz-covariance as time and spatial indices are handled differently. Since the propagator by itself is not a measurable quantity, this is not a problem as long as it does not lead to Lorentz-breaking measurable effects. As it turns out, this term indeed has an unobservable effect: it cancels with an other, similarly spurious term when evaluating $S$-matrix elements; see Exercise 8.6 of *Field Quantization* by Greiner & Reinhardt (around page 251 in my edition).

Comment: Thank you, btw there is still something I can't reproduce in the following steps... when I have time I will upload them.

Comment: @Filippo I updated the answer.